# How to prevent a method to mutate its arguments?

Tags: objective-c

This may be a very simple answer,but I cannot the solution anywhere.  I have this object called board that gets passed into a method.  I want to change the state of the board inside the method but not affected the board itself.  Here is a very simple version of the code that I attempted so far:

```
- (int) getMove:(Board*)board {

  Board* tempBoard = [[Board alloc] initSize:3];

  tempBoard.slots = board.slots;

  [tempBoard replaceIndex:5 withMark:@"X"];

  return 1;
}
```

If I were to call this method with a board object X, X has the changes made from that method.  I'm a noob at pointers so I'm thinking that is the cause of this.

Comment: What do you mean by "but not affected the board itself"?

Comment: If i call getMove with board1, and inside the method I would do a bunch of stuff to board1, I want board1 to stay exactly the same before calling the method.  does that make sense?

Comment: You fail to understand the difference between a *pointer* and an *object*.  I'd suggest you find some good reading material on object-oriented programming -- you won't last very long programming Objective-C without understanding the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want to prevent the board to be mutated, you should make the `Board` class immutable, i.e. not exposing any public method to change its internal state.

If you need also the mutable version, you can have a subclass like `MutableBoard` which exposes the methods to mutate the object.

So in the end you will be able to do

```
- (int)getMove:(Board *)board {
    [board makeMove]; // compiler error!
    return 1;
}
```

and

```
- (void)doSomethingOnTheBoard:(MutableBoard *)board {
     [board makeMove]; // ok!
}
```

I would also suggest you implement `-mutableCopy` on `Board` in order to support the creation of a mutable instance of it.

Bottom line, you just need to follow the same API design as `NSString`, `NSArray`, ... which are immutable, with an immutable subclass (`NSMutableString`, `NSMutableArray`...)

Apple has [a great guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ObjectMutability/ObjectMutability.html) to the concepts of objects mutability you can read.

Comment: so i were to do something like: [board makeMove:5] inside getMove, it won't change the board outside the method??

Comment: it will. `[board makeMove]` is not changing the pointer.

Comment: mutableCopy seems to be the solution i needed, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure? `mutableCopy` is actually a tiny part of a design change in your architecture. I doubt it will help you alone...